# ApostropheCMS: How to emit Events from Browser to Server

Tags: node.js, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I am new to Apostrophe and i cant find a solution for a communication between Client and Server.

I want to get some Data from my MySQL Database into my ApostropheCMS (i have a big Database with over 50k Rows). But i cant find a way, how to communicate between the Browser and the Server.

If i emit an Event from Client, it only triggers apos.on in the Browser, but not on the Server-side.

I cant find any answers in the Documentation, so i really need help.

Thanks for all answers

Comment: Provide an example of the code you have tried.

Comment: Like Alan said, a code example would be helpful. It sounds like you're trying to set up communication between a user's browser and your server. If that is the case, emit doesn't work like that - it would only work on the side it is triggered on (server -> server or browser -> browser). When you need to send data from the browser to the server, you'll want to implement some new routes/endpoints that can receive the data. There's an example of how to set the server to listen for requests and the browser to send the request here:
https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html

Comment: thanks for the fast answers. @Joseph this is a nice way to do it. I just thought there is maybe an other way. But thanks anyways, i think that is the way I will do it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apos.emit` mechanism is just a simple event bus (think of jQuery events) for use within the browser or server, not between them.

For messaging between browser and server, you of course have access to all the usual mechanisms of jQuery and Express, but there are some details to be aware of:

- On the server side, the easiest way to set up a route in one of your modules is typically to use the `route` method:

`self.route('post', 'do-cool-thing', function(req, res) {
  // here you can access req.body in the normal Express way, then...
  return res.send({ some: data, as: json });
}`

If your module is called `nifty`, then this route's URL will be `/modules/nifty/do-cool-thing`.

However, you can also access `self.apos.app`, which is the Express app object. So you can write:

`self.apos.app.post('/do-cool-thing', function(req, res) { ... });`

To create a route without the `/module/module-name` prefix.

On the browser side, you can communicate in the usual way through `$.post`, `$.ajax` and friends. Or, you can use our `$.jsonCall` plugin:

`$.jsonCall('/do-cool-thing', {
  some: data,
  sentAs: json,
  for: you
}, function(data) {
  // JSON response from the server, already parsed for you
}, function(err) {
  // Oh dear, a communications error
});`

One important thing to remember is that Apostrophe has built-in CSRF protection, to prevent third-party sites from tricking users into taking actions on your website. If you use jQuery's AJAX methods, including our jsonCall plugin, you will automatically participate and have no problems. If you use something else, like `fetch`, or wish to create an API for the rest of the world, then you'll need to be aware of this and add a CSRF exception.

For more information, see the [contact forms tutorial](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html#doing-it-your-way-a-note-on-c-s-r-f-protection), which covers this in detail.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. I hope you work on the Documentation a little bit more, because for an not even Semi-Professional Developer like me, it is really hard to understand most of it. That's because the documentation is written like "everyone should know that already, so i don't tell you more about it". And ApostropheCMS is way to awesome to be that bad documentated.

Comment: Your brutal honesty is appreciated. (: You came to this feeling from the tutorials? Or from your search for this particular information?

Comment: From the tutorials. The „getting started“ is cool and absolutely ok. But i miss more background informations. As Example: you use nunjucks, and this seems to be awesome. But i have never used it, just like mongodb or .less instead of regular css. And when i dive into the documentation i dont really understand anything of it, because i am an bloddy beginner with everyone of them, and so i dont really have a chance to really understand how they all work together. And even more important, i dont understand what comes from apostrophe and what from another solution. But thanks for your help!