# $.jsonCall results in error, but receives correct data

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

My `$.jsonCall` failed and succeeded at the same time.

index.js

```
afterConstruct: function(self) {
  self.pushAsset('script', 'form', { when: 'always' });

  self.route('post', 'submit', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Submitted! ' + req.body.hello);
  });
}
```

form.js

```
(function( $ ) {
  $('.crstn-privacy form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.jsonCall('/modules/privacy-widgets/submit', {
      hello: 'world'
    }, function(data) {
      console.log('Success:');
      console.log(data);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Error.');
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
})( jQuery );
```

widget.html

```
<div class="crstn-privacy">
  Privacy
  <form data-contact-form>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The error function returns an object with status `200` and the correct response: `Submitted! world`

Why is the success function not executed?

Comment: What is `$.jsonCall()`? Does it expect a JSON response? `Submitted! world` is not valid JSON.

Comment: I looked it up, its a [jquery-plugin](https://github.com/punkave/jquery-json-call/blob/master/jquery.json-call.js) used by apostrophe-cms and is pretty much identical to $.getJSON which makes it so weird since `getJSON` has been in jquery since 1.0 (2006!). The problem here though is that `res.send("something");` will not produce a json response. (edit: you type quickly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `jsonCall` is to do all of the following consistently:

1. Send the request via the POST method by default, which is appropriate for RPC-like APIs, where caching can only cause unexpected pain. This is different from `getJSON`.
2. Send the *request body data as JSON*, too, allowing all JSON types to be faithfully sent to the server unlike the text-only treatment of traditional form-data and its hacks to send objects and arrays. It is more efficient, although the server of course still should not trust it.
3. And yes, expect the response to be in JSON format.

The reason you are having an error is because you are not sending JSON to the browser. Note that we're talking about a browser-side plugin here, it cannot control what you are doing on the server side, that part is up to you.

So as for why you have to call `JSON.stringify` yourself:

Express (which Apostrophe is layered upon) is smart enough to automatically encode objects and arrays as JSON if you pass them to `res.send`. But if you `res.send` a string, the default behavior is to send that literal, actual string, which is useful in other types of routes that reply with HTML fragments or similar.

Our typical practice is to do something like this:

```
res.send({ status: 'ok', message: 'my message here' })
```

And on the browser side, look at `result.message` after first verifying that `result.status` is `ok`. `result` being of course the object we received via `jsonCall`.

It's reasonable to ask why we don't take a REST approach here. The reason is that REST doesn't always map one to one to the errors that might occur and we've found it makes more sense to use a more flexible status field. Your preference may vary, and of course no one is preventing you from writing your routes your way and communicating with them via `window.fetch`, `$.post` or whatever floats your boat. `$.jsonCall`, `self.api` and `self.html` (the latter two in code that extends widget players and modals) are conveniences. Use them if you want.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

`$.jsonCall()` requires the response to be JSON. The error is because it can't parse the response. Use `JSON.stringify()` when sending the response:

```
afterConstruct: function(self) {
  self.pushAsset('script', 'form', { when: 'always' });

  self.route('post', 'submit', function(req, res) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify('Submitted! ' + req.body.hello));
  });
}
```

Comment: or even `res.json()` which will stringify for you, or pass `res.send()` an object instead which will make `res.send()` use `res.json()` [under the hood](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/response.js#L141-L161).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't tried that because: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611128/9244077), ApostropheCMS should have parsed that for me already. I will open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: The issue is with SENDING the response, not parsing it.

Comment: I opened an issue, maybe ApostropheCMS should handle the sending. It is really smart. If not, it could be a point of improvement.

Comment: Is `res.send()` really calling something in ApostropheCMS, or is it just the normal method of node.js?

Comment: I don't know. But ApostropheCMS handles a lot for the developer, even in the browser. Maybe that too.

Comment: The problem here is on the server, not the browser. You may just need to call the correct ApostropheCMS function, instead of bypassing it by calling the low-level `res` methods.

Comment: Yeah, @Boutell's answer brings more light onto that. Thank you for your effort @Barmar!